# Resetting form does not work

Tags: angularjs

For some reason, my form does not want to reset after submit. I have a button with type `submit` and a button with type `button`. When using the button with type `button`, the form resets, but it does not with the other button.

I'm also using `var vm = this`.

The code for subtmitting:

```
vm.submit = function(form) {
   if (!form.$invalid) {
      vm.showQuestion(vm.indexOfQuestion);
      vm.putAnswer();
      form.$setPristine();
   }
}

<button class="button" type="submit" ng-click="vm.submit(testForm)">
        Volgende vraag
</button>
```

The code for `button` type button:

```
vm.resetForm = function(form) {
   form.$setPristine();
}


<button class="button" type="button" ng-click="vm.resetForm(testForm)">
        Test
</button>
```

My question is, why does the form not reset when `$setPristine()` is used in a subtmit button, but it works on a normal button? And how do I make it so it *does* reset after submitting after clicking the `submit` button?

Comment: There is a `button type = 'reset'`, you can pseudo click  this button after form submits. For this you would have to include a reset button on the page, hide it, click on it from the code behind.

Comment: I just changed the button type from ```button``` to ```reset```, but it does not reset the form.

Comment: This button is inside the form, right?

Comment: Yes, the button is inside the form.

Comment: @Sajal Found out that in order for the ```reset``` button to work, it needs ```value="Reset"```.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true. Only `type='reset'` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what the reason is of why it works, but resetting the form by using `$setPristine()` works by adding a `$timeout` function.

```
vm.submit = function(form) {
        if (!form.$invalid) {
          vm.showQuestion(vm.indexOfQuestion);
          vm.putAnswer();
          $timeout(function() {
            form.$setPristine();
          });

        }
      }
```